# How to check a string is not null?

Tags: java

```
if(string.equals(""))
{

}
```

How to check if the string is not null?

```
if(!string.equals(""))
{

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601978/how-to-check-if-my-string-is-equal-to-null

Comment: insignificant but, string.length() == 0 is probably better than say equals to ""

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Checking for null is done via `if (string != null)`

If you want to check if its null or empty - you'd need `if (string != null && !string.isEmpty())`

I prefer to use [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) `StringUtils.isNotEmpty(..)`

Comment: +1 for StringUtils, again. Everyone of us should spend a couple of minutes a day reading what apache commons can do for us!

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with the following code:

```
 if (string != null) {

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Checking for null is done by:

```
string != null
```

Your example is actually checking for the empty string

You can combine the two like this:

```
if (string != null && !string.equals("")) { ...
```

But null and empty are two different things

Answer (score 2):

Nothing really new to add to the answers above, just wrapping it into a simple class. *Commons-lang* is quite all right but if all you need are these or maybe a few more helper functions, rolling your own simple class is the easiest approach, also keeping executable size down.

```
public class StringUtils {

  public static boolean isEmpty(String s) {
    return (s == null || s.isEmpty());
  }

  public static boolean isNotEmpty(String s) {
    return !isEmpty(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(str != null && !str.isEmpty())
```

Be sure to use the parts of && in this order, because java will not proceed to evaluating the the second if the first part of && fails, thus ensuring you will not get a null pointer exception from str.isEmpty() if str is null.

Beware, it's only available since Java SE 1.6.

You have to check `str.length() == 0 or str.equals("")` 
on previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

Use TextUtils Method.

[TextUtils.isEmpty(str)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) : Returns true if the string is null or 0-length. Parameters: str the string to be examined Returns: true if str is null or zero length

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(str)){
    // str is null or lenght is 0
}
```

[Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b2c4f0bf11f38fd31d80f1256c89b9db043a2929/core/java/android/text/TextUtils.java) of TextUtils class

isEmpty Method :

```
 public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence str) {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Comment: U can found here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

As everyone is saying, you'd have to check (string!=null), in objects you're testing the memory pointer.

because every object is identified by a memory pointer, you have to check your object for a null pointer before testing anything else, so:

(string!=null && !string.equals("")) is good

(!string.equals("") && string !=null) can give you a nullpointerexception.

if you don't care for trailing spaces you can always use trim() before equals()
so " " and "" gives you the same result

Answer (score 0):

The best way to check a String is :

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(string)){
....
}
```

From the [doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-) :

> isBlank(CharSequence cs) :
>
> Checks if a CharSequence is empty (""), null
> or whitespace only.

Comment: You should specify its library full name, Commons, and be more specific on the method behaviour. Imho, you should improve the answer a bit. Regards

Comment: @FabianoTarlao Sure buddy, have updated the answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can use Predicate and its new method (since java 11) [Predicate::not](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#not(java.util.function.Predicate))

You can write code to check if string is not null and not empty:

```java
Predicate<String> notNull = Predicate.not(Objects::isNull);
Predicate<String> notEmptyString = Predicate.not(String::isEmpty);
Predicate<String> isNotEmpty = notNull.and(notEmptyString);
```

Then you can test it:

```java
System.out.println(isNotEmpty.test(""));      // false
System.out.println(isNotEmpty.test(null));    // false
System.out.println(isNotEmpty.test("null"));  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

A common way for testing null string in Java is with `Optionals`:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(myString).orElse("value was null")
```

```java
Optional.ofNullable(myString).ifPresent(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

```java
Optional.ofNullable(myString).orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("value was null"));
```

And to test if it is null or empty you can use Apache `org.apache.commons.lang3` library that gives you the following methods:

- `StringUtils.isEmpty(String) / StringUtils.isNotEmpty(String)`: It tests if the String is null or empty (" " is not empty)
- `StringUtils.isBlank(String) / StringUtils.isNotBlank(String)`: Same as isEmpty bt if the String is only whitespace it is considered blank

And applied to `Optional` you get:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(myString).filter(StringUtils::isNotEmpty).orElse("value was null or empty");
```

Comment: Do not do this. It is only complicated without any benefit over the accepted answer.

Comment: It's a one-liner that does the same as 
```java
if(myString != null){
   ...
}
```
That you find it complicated it's a thing but I assume you find Java lambda complicated to read too ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Strings.isNullOrEmpty("")` from `com.google.common.base.Strings` this method returns *boolean* value and checks for both null and empty string.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(string != null)
```

or

```
if(string.length() == 0)
```

or

```
if(("").equals(string))
```

Comment: Not really. Only the first is really true.

Answer (score -4):

u can try this

```
if(string != null)
```

Comment: what about multiple spaces