# Check if is it empty on edit text is not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

What i have is android app , and in one of activities i have two edit text with button, and i want either if one of them were empty when i click the button to preform a toast to tell the user to enter data, and if it was not empty i want it to open intent and do other thing , here is my code :

```
add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(quantity.getText()==null){
                    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity2.this,"please enter quantity",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if(extra.getText()==null){
                    Toast.makeText(FullImageActivity2.this,"please enter extra",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                Quan=quantity.getText().toString();
                name=itemId;
                image=R.drawable.products;
                Intent cart=new Intent(FullImageActivity2.this,CartList.class);
                cart.putExtra("name", name);
                cart.putExtra("quantity",Quan);
                cart.putExtra("image", image);
                Log.e("quan",Quan+"");
                Log.e("name",name+"");
                startActivity(cart);
                }
            }
        });
```

But the weird thing that if they were empty , else is working !! which is not logic at all .. the validation on empty text is not empty , Why this is happening?? Help plz

Comment: `quantity.getText()==null` what you do here? Do you know what `null` actually means?

Comment: i am new at android .. i don't know what does it mean here probably !!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601978/how-to-check-if-my-string-is-equal-to-null and do what @ZerO says

Comment: @sereen well this is first lesson in Java :-/

Comment: what does it do with divide with zero? can you remove the unvote please? they gave me an answer .. it worked :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
if(editText.getText().toString().length()<1){
//do something
}
```

And of course you are **mistaking** null with "" which means no string but not null.

Answer (score 2):

Try to used `.equals()` method

```
if(quantity.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
```

Comment: this will work. And put this in a thread which contains a loop. this way, the thread will automatically check for an input again and again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601978/how-to-check-if-my-string-is-equal-to-null

Answer (score 0):

When Edittext is empty, getText() method returns empty string, not null.
Try:

```
if(quantity.getText().toString().equals("")){
```

Of course, if you want to avoid entering only spaces, use

```
if(quantity.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
```