# Picasso not load images from SharedPreferences after saved

Tags: android, image, save, loading, picasso

Sorry for my English.
My app take a photo and after i use picasso to load in a image view and save the image Uri in sharedpreferences.
the image load fine when take or select the picture but when close the activity and 
reopen the image not show. What happen?

```
private SharedPreferencesManager mSharedPreferencesManager;
private ImageView imageProfile;
private Uri mMediaUri;

private DialogInterface.OnClickListener mDialogClickListenerToNewMessage = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        switch (which) {
        case 0:
            //Take Picture
            Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            mMediaUri = getOutPutMediaUri(AppConstants.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            if (mMediaUri == null) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyProfileActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.problem_accessing_the_memory_of_your_device) 
                .setTitle(R.string.sorry_)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialogMemory = builder.create();
                dialogMemory.show();
            } else {
                takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mMediaUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePhotoIntent, AppConstants.TAKE_PHOTO_REQUEST);
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            //Choose Picture
            Intent choosePhotoIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            choosePhotoIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(choosePhotoIntent, AppConstants.PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

};

private Uri getOutPutMediaUri(int mediaType) {
    if (isExternalStoregeAvailable()) {
        //get Uri

        //1.- Get the external storage directory
        String appName = getString(R.string.app_name);
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),appName);

        //2.- Create our subdirectory
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdir()) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyProfileActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.failed_to_created_directory_) 
                .setTitle(R.string.sorry_)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialogMemory = builder.create();
                dialogMemory.show();
                return null;
            }
        }
        //3.- Create a file name
        File mediaFile;
        Date currentDate = new Date();
        String timesTamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(currentDate);

        //4.- Crate the file
        String path = mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator;
        if (mediaType == AppConstants.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(path + "IMG_" + timesTamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (mediaType == AppConstants.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(path + "VID_" + timesTamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        //5.- Return the file's URI
        return Uri.fromFile(mediaFile);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private boolean isExternalStoregeAvailable(){
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //add file to the Gallery
        if (requestCode == AppConstants.PICK_PHOTO_REQUEST) {
            if (data == null) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(R.string.failed_to_get_a_file_from_the_gallery) 
                .setTitle(R.string.sorry_)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            } else {
                mMediaUri = data.getData();
                mSharedPreferencesManager.savePhotoUri(mMediaUri.toString());

            }

        } else {
            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(mMediaUri);
            sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            mSharedPreferencesManager.savePhotoUri(mMediaUri.toString());
        }

        Picasso.with(MyProfileActivity.this).load(mMediaUri).into(imageProfile);

    } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.error_adding_file_to_gallery) 
        .setTitle(R.string.sorry_)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

My code in onResume method

```
mSharedPreferencesManager =  new SharedPreferencesManager(this);
final String uri = mSharedPreferencesManager.getPhotoUri();

    if (!uri.equals("null")) {
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(uri);
        Picasso.with(MyProfileActivity.this).load(imageUri).into(imageProfile);
    }

//Code to get photo uri in sharedpreferences manager
public String getPhotoUri(){
    String photoUri = sharedPreferences.getString(PHOTO_URI, "null");
    return photoUri;
}

if (uri != "null") {
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(uri);
        Picasso.with(MyProfileActivity.this).load(imageUri).into(imageProfile, new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MyProfileActivity.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MyProfileActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

change your `if statement` from

```
if (!uri.equals("null"))
```

to:

```
if (uri != null)
```

for further see below:

[How to check if my string is equal to null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601978/how-to-check-if-my-string-is-equal-to-null)

Comment: that's not the problem, i use this

Comment: you should have put  `String photoUri = sharedPreferences.getString(PHOTO_URI, "null");` first

Comment: if (uri != "null") to if (uri != null)

Comment: `allways return error in callback` whats the error?

Comment: this is getPhotoUri()

Comment: `This code is the same as I have in this method` not having quotation man !!

Comment: thanks for all your answers, and solved the problem, the problem was that the name of the string can not be "uri" if the same is not a Uri, just change the name and the problem was solved