# Action delay after entered EditText Value

Tags: java, android

hi am trying to allow the user to change the delay time after an action is performed on button click..i tried this where time is the Edit Text and used time instead of a number under the handler.

```
Long delay=time.getText().toString().trim();
```

but i am getting and error incompatible types if anyone have a solution for this please help i know it is simple but i am not getting it.

code

```
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {



            String tittle=ed1.getText().toString().trim();
            String subject=ed2.getText().toString().trim();
            String body=ed3.getText().toString().trim();

            NotificationManager notif=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notify=new Notification(R.drawable.noti,tittle,System.currentTimeMillis());
            PendingIntent pending= PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);

            notify.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(),subject,body,pending);
            notif.notify(0, notify);
                }
            }, 12000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incompatible types error is because you are assigning a `String` value to a `long` variable. You have to convert the `String` value to `long` before you can store it in `delay` variable.

Do something like

```
String delayStr = time.getText().toString().trim();
long delay = Long.parseLong(delayStr);
```

or in one line

```
long delay = Long.parseLong(time.getText().toString().trim());
```

Comment: pass `delay` variable as 2nd parameter to `postDelayed` in handler. i.e Replace `12000` with `delay`.

Comment: yes ive triend that before you say :p and worked thanks for helping.

Comment: rogerthatcode when no value is entered the app force close i tried if (!delayStr=null){//my code}

Comment: because string comparison is not done that what. do you have an error logcat? try [this ans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601978/how-to-check-if-my-string-is-equal-to-null). If you still have problem. Please ask a new question as its a different one.