# How can I avoid this NullPointerException?

Tags: java

I have the following situation, where my program terminates with a NullPointerException during the function. What can I do to make this function work?

**UPDATE**

```
else if (str == null)
    emptyLinks.add(newPageLinks.get(i).getText() + "at link: " + str);
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601978/how-to-check-if-my-string-is-equal-to-null

Comment: Please provide some more code

Comment: `str == null` should not give you a nullpointer exception for a null String

Comment: if String is null, it points to no memory object. That is why you cannot call any method because there is no object. And thats why you are getting NPE

Comment: What is in your `do something`?

Comment: I have updated my do something function.

Comment: Shouldn't your code only execute if `str != null`? Why would you want to concatenate a null String?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis not really a duplicate...

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis this is not a duplicate and those answers on the other page are not even close to a help.

Comment: You'd think so, but you'd be wrong. A `NullPointerException` occurs for one reason only, dereferencing a `null` value. You've posted some piece of code where 4 things could be `null`. We are not a debugging service. Read the duplicate, understand what a NPE is and use the details there to identify what is `null` in your code.

Comment: The answers you've received below are essentially stating the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in:

```
else if (str == null)
```

The actual problem is in:

```
do something
```

In your do something you are trying to access a property or method of a null object which isn't possible and will throw an NPE.

Normally if you want to access methods from an object that could be `null` you do a `null` check like so:

```
if (str != null)
do something
```

Comment: I have added my do something function to my question, can you help me with this?

Comment: @SourceCode the problem isn't `str` probably either `emptyLinks` is null or `newPageLinks` is null look at your stacktrace it should help you...

Comment: emptyLinks is an empty queue.. how can I add this string to it?

Comment: Why the downvote please specify why if you downvote someone.

Answer (score 1):

If you use str == null the NullPointerException shouldn't be thrown.
You can use:

```
 if (str == null || str.equals("null"))
    do something
```

If first condition is true then second conditions won't be evaluated and the exception won't be thrown.

Probably your problem is in do something when the str is null.