# File not Saving

Tags: java, file, class, properties

anyone can pin point why it is not letting me save my Booking file? It is giving me an exception after trying to save the Customer Name. Cant see any errors also so don't know exactly what is wrong. Thanks

```
 private void savebookingButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
        Booking customerbooking = new Booking();
        Customer customerfile = customerbooking.getCustomer();

        try {
            if (custnameTF.getText().equals("")) {
                throw new EmptyField("Please Insert Customer");
            } else {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Bookings/" + custidTF.getText() + ".txt");
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

                customerfile.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));
                customerfile.setPersonSurname((custsurnameTF.getText()));
                customerfile.setPersonID((custidTF.getText()));
                customerfile.setConsultantname(consnameTF.getText());
                customerfile.setConsultantsurname((conssurnameTF.getText()));
                customerfile.setConsulid(considTF.getText());
                customerbooking.setFlightlocation(locationCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setFlighttime(timeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setFlightfee(feeCB.getSelectedItem().toString());
                customerbooking.setCar(carRB.isSelected());
                customerbooking.setInsurance(insuranceRB.isSelected());

                oos.writeObject(customerbooking);
                oos.close();
                fos.close();

                custnameTF.setText("");
                custsurnameTF.setText("");
                custidTF.setText("");
                considTF.setText("");
                consnameTF.setText("");
                conssurnameTF.setText("");
                locationCB.setSelectedItem("");
                timeCB.setSelectedItem("");
                feeCB.setSelectedItem("");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Booking was Saved Successfully!",
                        "Success", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Booking could not be Saved!",
                    "Error!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } catch (EmptyField ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Insert Customer",
                    "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

        dispose();

    }
```

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at airline.booking.system.BookingFrame.savebookingButtonActionPerformed(BookingFrame.java:357)
    at airline.booking.system.BookingFrame.access$200(BookingFrame.java:21)
    at airline.booking.system.BookingFrame$3.actionPerformed(BookingFrame.java:102)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Can you add "e.printStackTrace()" so we can see where the error is coming from? Also, are you sure the file path exists?

Comment: And the exception is...?

Comment: Exception added. Thanks

Comment: You need to step through your code and find out what's null and why. Check the duplicate.

Comment: The error is on line 357 of BookingFrame.java. In your code snippet, we can't tell which line is 357, so can't give any more advice.

Comment: Ye you are right.. line 357 is : customerfile.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));

Comment: Well, then you should check if `customerbooking.getCustomer()` returns `null` and why it does that.

Answer (score 1):

When you are checking `custnameTF.getText()` you aren't actually checking to see if it is null.  There is a difference between an empty string and an null string.  Add in a check like `custnameTF.getText() != null` and that should throw the exception you programmed instead of going through to a null pointer.

Comment: Good eye! That seems like the correct answer to me.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me, that this is the problem. OP said that the exception occurs here: `customerfile.setPersonName((custnameTF.getText()));`. If `custnameTF` is `null`, then why should it fail on the _second_ call? I also don't think that a TextField would return `null` for `getText`.

Comment: There is also a difference between comparing a value and using a value.  If a field is null, you can still compare it to whatever you want, but you cannot set a null value to another variable.  This is why it doesn't fail on the first call, just the second.

Comment: This makes even less sense. You suggested to include the check `custnameTF.getText() != null`, so you think that `custnameTF.getText()` returns `null`. And then you say that this `custnameTF.getText().equals("")` wouldn't fail ... because `null.equals("")` is possible? And *"but you cannot set a null value to another variable"* is either unclear or wrong. You can set every variable to `null` if it isn't a primitive type.

Comment: [THIS THREAD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601978/how-to-check-if-my-string-is-equal-to-null)  explains procedure to check for null values in strings.  You must do this first in order to avoid Null Pointer Exceptions.

Comment: I know how to check for `null`, but it seems that you don't understand, that `custnameTF.getText()` can't be `null` if the NPE occurs one the line OP mentioned. Maybe sometime you will see, that it is `customerfile` that is `null`. Not meant to be offending.